# how to apply angular2-multiselect-dropdown settings dynamically based on checkbox?

Tags: angular

We got ngFor inside that loop We got a checkbox and angular2-multiselect-dropdown, so here We need to enable angular2-multiselect-dropdown only when check box is checked.

```
<div *ngFor="let country of country_list; index as id">
<input (click)="unsetDisable($event, id)" name="check_level_{{id}}"
         type="checkbox" id={{id}} value={{id}} />

<angular2-multiselect id="id_first_level_{{id}}" [(ngModel)]="selected_levels"
                                                        (onSelect)="onItemSelect($event, id)"
                                                        (onDeSelect)="OnItemDeSelect($event, id)"
                                                        (onSelectAll)="onSelectAll($event, id)"
                                                        (onDeSelectAll)="onDeSelectAll($event, id)"
                                                        formControlName="level1" [data]="dropdownList" required
                                                        id="id_team_members" [(settings)]="country_settings[id].settings1"></angular2-multiselect>
</div>
```

In TS file,

```
ngOnInit(){
for( let i=0; i < country_data.length; i++){
      this.country_settings.push({
      settings1: {text:'Select', disabled : true, enableSearchFilter: true}
      })
    }
}

unsetDisable(event,index){
    if(event.target.checked === true){
      this.country_settings[index].settings1.disabled = false;
      console.log(this.country_settings[index].settings1);
      //get data
    }else{
      this.country_settings[index].settings1.disabled = true;
    }

  }
```

Comment: What is your current issue? Do you get any error?

Comment: According to your code, [(settings)]="country_settings[id].settings" should have to be [(settings)]="country_settings[id].settings1" right?

Comment: @Koga yes that one is typo. We have to enable multiselect only when check box is clicked.